# Why doesn't the following call to 'at' execute the bash script?

Tags: shell-script, at

I made a bash script called `test.sh` that contains the following:

```
#!/#bin/bash

echo "Done!"
```

I enter `bash test.sh | at 1549`:

```
myusername@machine:path$ bash test.sh | at 1549
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 4 at Fri Sep  3 15:49:00 2021
myusername@machine:path$ date
Fri Sep  3 15:48:22 EDT 2021
myusername@machine:path$ date
Fri Sep  3 15:49:12 EDT 2021
```

Why does it appear that the script was not executed?  Is it because my shell is bash as shown below?

```
myusername@machine:path$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: That is a strange shebang. As you use `bash` as command for the script it would run OK, but if ran as stand-alone the system would likely go bananas trying to interpret the line. You say interpreter is `/#bin/sh` which I can not see how it would normally exist.

Comment: that should probably be `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 5):

You are executing the script immediately, and scheduling *its output* for execution by `at`. Needless to say this fails.

What I think you want is this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Done!"
```

Consider you have written this to a file called `myscript`.

Make it executable:

```
chmod a+x myscript
```

Then queue it for execution at 15:49 and capture the output in `myscript.log` (if you don't capture the output it gets emailed to your local UNIX/Linux account, or if there is no mail subsystem installed at all then it's simply discarded):

```
at 1549 <<'X'
./myscript > myscript.log 2>&1
X
```

Comment: Very well written answer!

Comment: @FKEInternet thank you. I'm glad you found it useful

Answer (score 3):

Any output from a command executed through the `at` system, is sent on via email.

Secondly, when they are executed, it has disassociated itself from your current tty, so is unable to interact with it, even if you wanted it to.

Comment: What does it mean that it is sent on via email?

Comment: It's sent via `/usr/sbin/sendmail`. Please read the `at` man page. If you don't have an email infrastructure set up, then either run `mail`, or look at the contents of the `/var/spool/mail` directory.

Comment: ... thirdly, `bash test.sh | at 1549` runs `bash test.sh` *now* and passes its *output* to `at`, which will therefore attempt to execute a command named `Done!` at 15:49